# Calling service from within a service?

Tags: php, symfony

Im trying to call a method within a service that calls ANOTHER method from another service.

Current class -> different class/service -> to different class/service

I can successfully call the initial service, but when that service tries calling an additional service i get the error

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

Heres the code that causes the error:

```
$edmt = $this->get('endorsements');
```

And the declaration of the service:

```
endorsements:
    class:        EndorseMe\EndorsementBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    arguments: [ @router, @service_container]
```

However, to make things trickier, this service isnt always used as a service. Its also regular symfony controller. It needs to be able to work both ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be passing your second service to your first service as a parameter:

```
endorsements:
    class:     EndorseMe\EndorsementBundle\Controller\DefaultController
    arguments: [ @router, @service_container, @your_second_service ]
```

Then in your first service:

```
protected $injectedService;

public function __construct(SecondServiceClass $injectedService)
{
    $this->injectedService = $injectedService;
}
```

After that you should be able to use the injected service by calling `$this->injectedService`

Take a look at the [Referencing Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) chapter in the documentation.

**EDIT:** I don't think it's possible to use the same class both as Service and Controller. I suggest to [define Controller as Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) instead. In the end you would have your second service injected in your first service, and your first service injected in your controller service (three services total).

Comment: Nice! Would that work even when i use the class as a non-service (just a regular class)?

Comment: From a regular class your should do $service = $this->get('your_first_service'); as usual.

Comment: That i understand. The issue is the service `this_is_your_service` will not always be used as a service. Sometimes, its used as a regular symfony controller. It needs to be able to work both ways

Comment: That is an entirely different question, I believe. Edit your original question or post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

**Since 2017 and Symfony 3.3** this gets very simple.

#### 1. Register services with autowiring

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    EndorseMe\EndorsementBundle\:
        resource: ../../src/EndorseMe/EndorsementBundle
```

#### 2. Require any service in any other service via Constructor Injection

```
<?php

namespace EndorseMe\EndorsementBundle;

class MyService
{
    /**
     * @var AnotherService 
     */
    private $anotherService;

    public function __construct(AnotherService $anotherService)
    {
        $this->anotherService = $anotherService;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $this->anotherService->someAnotherMethod();
    }
}
```

That's all!

---

**To get more Symfony 3.3 Dependency Injection news examples before/after, [just check this post](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/).**